# LetsEncrypt could not connect to verify the domain (timeout)

Tags: nginx, port-forwarding, letsencrypt, nextcloud

I'm trying to set up a SSL certificate for my Nextcloud server with LetsEncrypt, but when I run:

```
$ sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/nextcloud --agree-tos \
     --no-eff-email --email email@domain.com -d cloud.domain.com --rsa-key-size 4096
```

*(based on this tutorial: https://howto.wared.fr/ubuntu-installation-nextcloud-nginx/)*

I got this error message:

```
Failed authorization procedure. cloud.domain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: 
The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain ::
Fetching http://cloud.domain.com/...: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
```

*(I have already opened firewall ports 80 & 443)*

As my router only uses IPv6, I could not set up the port forwarding to point to my server (ubuntu 18.04), is that the most potential problem? If yes, do I have to contact my ISP to re-enable IPv4?

If no, what could it be?

Comment: Forget about LetsEncrypt for a bit. First solve the problem of connecting to your server.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need to ensure public **IPv4** is enabled on your router. Without it only a handful of people would be able to connect to you, that taken into account, I believe you have some firewall issue on your server. Please post:

```
sudo iptables --list --verbose --line-numbers
```

> As my router only uses IPv6, I could not set up the port forwarding to point on my server (ubuntu 18.04), is that the most potential problem? If yes, do I have to contact my ISP to re-enable IPv4?

As I don't fully grasp this sentence, I will say:

- You need IPv4 public IP address assigned on your router
- If you don't have it, then yes, you need to contact your provider

---

Afterwards, please make sure you have forwarded ports 80 and 443 from your router to your server.

Comment: You don't need IPv4, but without it few people will be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps anyone, If you using an **Amazon EC2 instance**, first try to check the DNS propagation is successfully set, you can use:
**https://letsdebug.net/**
If everything correct, then try to verify if your group security (EC2 > Security Groups > nameOfGroup) has these Inbound rules:

```
Type          |   Protocol  |  Port range | Source    | Description - optional
HTTP          |   TCP       |   80        | 0.0.0.0/0 | -
SSH           |   TCP       |   22        | 0.0.0.0/0 | -   
HTTPS         |   TCP       |   443       | 0.0.0.0/0 | -
```